# How can I delete a specific JSON array (consultas) embedded within another JSON array (f7Contacts) both saved in a single localSorage key?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a localStorage key (f7Contacts) stored as a JSON array, as it should be. I know how to delete the whole key using `localStorage.removeItem("myKey");`.

My array, as you can see is formed by a set of JSON arrays embeeded inside of it. There is the wider one named **f7Contacts** and inside of it there are some subarrays (to name them someway) named **visitings** and **consultas**. Now, what I'm trying to delete is not a single item from any of the JSON arrays nor the whole **f7Contacts** array but the JSON sub array named **consultas**.

I have tried so many ways but I could not get a working code.

This is what I've got until now:

My stringify array looks like this:

(now I have up dated the string to make it more alike my real case because the proposed answers manage to delete the `consultas` just in one of the contacts, and in a case it deletes the `consultas` from the first contact and deletes the rest of the contacts. I named ELISA and FRANK for you to differetiate them. Also updated my Javascript and html as a mixture from my own code and the one of ЖнецЪ's answer. I did this to keep my enviroment consistent. This code manage to delete the **consultas** of the first **contact** but also deletes the rest of the **contacts**.):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var contacts = [{
     id: "95470e9e-ee5c-4467-9500-1fcbeae1b57c",
     hasPic: true,
     picId: 3,
     createdOn: "2021-08-01T17:31:32.230Z",
     firstName: "ELISA",
     company: "La Fábrica",
     job: "Barrendero",
     mobile: "+53555555",
     phone: "+5372222222",
     sms: "",
     email: "fulano@nauta.cu",
     madedate: "Invalid date",
     clinic: "2",
     gender: "M",
     birthday: "Invalid date",
     age: "47",
     visitings: [{
        id: "1",
        vdate: "19/07/-2006 12:00 AM",
        pdcb: "Est officia dolorem ",
        vdiagnose: "Laborum Ea consecte",
        vrecom: "Mollit cillum sed pe",
        nextv: "Invalid date"
     }],

     consultas: [{
          id: "1",
          ldate: "04/07/-1978 12:00 AM",
          lmotive: "Soluta cumque aspern",
          ldiagnose: "Quidem autem do ut o",
          ttest: "Rerum sint atque il",
          etest: "Officiis deserunt un",
          mtest: "Nihil a dolore rem s",
          nextv: "Invalid date"
        },

        {
          id: "2",
          ldate: "04/04/-1991 12:00 AM",
          lmotive: "Eius in est enim no",
          ldiagnose: "In aliqua Sunt dol",
          ttest: "Sunt dolor eu sed N",
          etest: "Quia aut reprehender",
          mtest: "Unde libero autem an",
          nextv: "Invalid date"
        }
     ],
     isFavorite: true
    },
    {id: "95470e9e-ee5c-4467-9500-1fcbeae1b57c",
     hasPic: true,
     picId: 3,
     createdOn: "2021-08-01T17:31:32.230Z",
     firstName: "FRANK",
     company: "La Fábrica",
     job: "Barrendero",
     mobile: "+53555555",
     phone: "+5372222222",
     sms: "",
     email: "fulano@nauta.cu",
     madedate: "Invalid date",
     clinic: "2",
     gender: "M",
     birthday: "Invalid date",
     age: "47",
     visitings: [{
        id: "1",
        vdate: "19/07/-2006 12:00 AM",
        pdcb: "Est officia dolorem ",
        vdiagnose: "Laborum Ea consecte",
        vrecom: "Mollit cillum sed pe",
        nextv: "Invalid date"
    }],

     consultas: [{
          id: "1",
          ldate: "04/07/-1978 12:00 AM",
          lmotive: "Soluta cumque aspern",
          ldiagnose: "Quidem autem do ut o",
          ttest: "Rerum sint atque il",
          etest: "Officiis deserunt un",
          mtest: "Nihil a dolore rem s",
          nextv: "Invalid date"
        },

        {
          id: "2",
          ldate: "04/04/-1991 12:00 AM",
          lmotive: "Eius in est enim no",
          ldiagnose: "In aliqua Sunt dol",
          ttest: "Sunt dolor eu sed N",
          etest: "Quia aut reprehender",
          mtest: "Unde libero autem an",
          nextv: "Invalid date"
        }
    ],

    isFavorite: true
    }];

  // Get from lS
    const lS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts'));
    // DOM elements
    const cancelBtn = document.getElementById('dntdelete');
    const deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete');
    const consultas = document.getElementById('consultas');
    const json = document.getElementById('json');


    function clearConsults(){
    document.getElementById('confirm').style.display="block";
    {
    function removeItem() {
    const lS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts'));
    if (!lS) return;

    const obj = lS[0];
    // Find 'consultas' key in the object
    const findKey = Object.keys(obj).find(key => key.includes('consultas'));
    if (findKey) {
      // Delete key from the object with array
      delete obj[findKey];
    }
    // Back wraping the obj into array & put to the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify([obj])); //set item back into storage
    }
    alert('CONSULTAS ELIMINADAS');
    document.getElementById('confirm').style.display="none";

    if (lS[0].consultas) {
    consultas.textContent = lS[0].consultas.length;
    }
    consultas.textContent = 0;
    json.textContent = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);
    }

    cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', dntdelete);
    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', clearConsults);
    }
    });

    document.getElementById('dntdelete').onclick = function(){
    alert('OPERACIÓN CANCELADA');
    document.getElementById('confirm').style.display="none";
    return false;
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<main>
<div class="results">
<h4>Consultas<span id="consultas"></span></h4>
</div>
<div class="control-buttons">
<div id="confirm" style="display: none">
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
<button id="dntdelete">Cancel</button>
</div>
<a onclick="clearConsults()">Delete Consultas</a><h3>SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE?</h3>
</div>
</main>
```

I must let it clear that this **localStorage key (f7Contacts)** is really stored by another js within the app and if I have included the **localStorage.setItem("f7Contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));** at the beginning of my code above is just as an attempt to make it clear for you. And let clear too that there are several contacts within the string and the task is to delete `consultas` for them all.

Comment: You want to use `JSON.parse` to convert the json string to an array, then remove the items you want, then convert the updated array back to string and save it as the same key in `localStorage`.

Comment: Hi, Ray, out of all the reading I've done since here I know that's the logic behind what I need to do but as my javascript skills are very limited I do not know how to do this. Could you, please, help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm right understood you want removed only `consultas` from the `localStorage`. I think better to find the key of the object with `Object.keys` and then delete that key from the object. [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Jnetc/c7610tdw/12/)

**script.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var contacts = [
    {
      id: '95470e9e-ee5c-4467-9500-1fcbeae1b57c',
      hasPic: true,
      picId: 3,
      createdOn: '2021-08-01T17:31:32.230Z',
      firstName: 'ELISA',
      company: 'La Fábrica',
      job: 'Barrendero',
      mobile: '+53555555',
      phone: '+5372222222',
      sms: '',
      email: 'fulano@nauta.cu',
      madedate: 'Invalid date',
      clinic: '2',
      gender: 'M',
      birthday: 'Invalid date',
      age: '47',
      visitings: [
        {
          id: '1',
          vdate: '19/07/-2006 12:00 AM',
          pdcb: 'Est officia dolorem ',
          vdiagnose: 'Laborum Ea consecte',
          vrecom: 'Mollit cillum sed pe',
          nextv: 'Invalid date',
        },
      ],

      consultas: [
        {
          id: '1',
          ldate: '04/07/-1978 12:00 AM',
          lmotive: 'Soluta cumque aspern',
          ldiagnose: 'Quidem autem do ut o',
          ttest: 'Rerum sint atque il',
          etest: 'Officiis deserunt un',
          mtest: 'Nihil a dolore rem s',
          nextv: 'Invalid date',
        },

        {
          id: '2',
          ldate: '04/04/-1991 12:00 AM',
          lmotive: 'Eius in est enim no',
          ldiagnose: 'In aliqua Sunt dol',
          ttest: 'Sunt dolor eu sed N',
          etest: 'Quia aut reprehender',
          mtest: 'Unde libero autem an',
          nextv: 'Invalid date',
        },
      ],
      isFavorite: true,
    },
    {
      id: '95470e9e-ee5c-4467-9500-1fcbeae1b57c',
      hasPic: true,
      picId: 3,
      createdOn: '2021-08-01T17:31:32.230Z',
      firstName: 'FRANK',
      company: 'La Fábrica',
      job: 'Barrendero',
      mobile: '+53555555',
      phone: '+5372222222',
      sms: '',
      email: 'fulano@nauta.cu',
      madedate: 'Invalid date',
      clinic: '2',
      gender: 'M',
      birthday: 'Invalid date',
      age: '47',
      visitings: [
        {
          id: '1',
          vdate: '19/07/-2006 12:00 AM',
          pdcb: 'Est officia dolorem ',
          vdiagnose: 'Laborum Ea consecte',
          vrecom: 'Mollit cillum sed pe',
          nextv: 'Invalid date',
        },
      ],

      consultas: [
        {
          id: '1',
          ldate: '04/07/-1978 12:00 AM',
          lmotive: 'Soluta cumque aspern',
          ldiagnose: 'Quidem autem do ut o',
          ttest: 'Rerum sint atque il',
          etest: 'Officiis deserunt un',
          mtest: 'Nihil a dolore rem s',
          nextv: 'Invalid date',
        },

        {
          id: '2',
          ldate: '04/04/-1991 12:00 AM',
          lmotive: 'Eius in est enim no',
          ldiagnose: 'In aliqua Sunt dol',
          ttest: 'Sunt dolor eu sed N',
          etest: 'Quia aut reprehender',
          mtest: 'Unde libero autem an',
          nextv: 'Invalid date',
        },
      ],
      isFavorite: true,
    },
  ];

  // Get from lS
  const lS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts'));
  // DOM elements
  const clearConsultsBtn = document.getElementById('clear-consults');
  const confirmBtn = document.getElementById('confirm');
  const createBtn = document.getElementById('create');
  const cancelBtn = document.getElementById('dntdelete');
  const deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete');
  const consultas = document.getElementById('consultas');
  const controlBtns = document.querySelector('.control-buttons');
  const json = document.getElementById('json');
  // Check if not lS
  if (!lS) {
    localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify(contacts));

    /// JUST FOR VISIBILITY
    let num = 0;
    for (const i of contacts) {
      num += i.consultas.length;
      consultas.textContent = num;
    }
    json.textContent = JSON.stringify(contacts, undefined, 2);
  }

  if (lS) {
    for (const i of lS) {
      if (!i.consultas) consultas.textContent = 0;
    }
    json.textContent = JSON.stringify(lS, undefined, 2);
  }

  function removeItem() {
    const lS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts'));
    if (!lS) return;

    // Creating new array without 'consultas'
    const clearArray = lS.map(obj => {
      // Find 'consultas' key in the object
      const findKey = Object.keys(obj).find(key => key.includes('consultas'));
      if (findKey) {
        // Delete key from the object with array
        delete obj[findKey];
      }
      return obj; // Returning object to array without 'consultas'
    });
    // Put to the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify(clearArray)); //set item back into storage
    alert('CONSULTAS ELIMINADAS');
    controlBtns.style.display = 'none';
    clearConsultsBtn.style.display = 'block';

    /// JUST FOR VISIBILITY
    if (clearArray) {
      for (const i of clearArray) {
        if (!i.consultas) consultas.textContent = 0;
      }
    }
    json.textContent = JSON.stringify(clearArray, undefined, 2);
  }

  function addItem() {
    localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify(contacts));

    /// JUST FOR VISIBILITY
    let num = 0;
    for (const i of contacts) {
      num += i.consultas.length;
      consultas.textContent = num;
    }
    json.textContent = JSON.stringify(contacts, undefined, 2);
  }

  function clearConsults() {
    alert('OPERACIÓN CANCELADA');
    controlBtns.style.display = 'flex';
    clearConsultsBtn.style.display = 'none';
  }

  function cancel() {
    alert('OPERACIÓN CANCELADA');
    controlBtns.style.display = 'none';
    clearConsultsBtn.style.display = 'block';
  }

  clearConsultsBtn.addEventListener('click', clearConsults);
  createBtn.addEventListener('click', addItem);
  cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', cancel);
  deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
  confirmBtn.addEventListener('click', clearConsults);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<main>
  <div class="results">
    <h4>Consultas arrays<span id="consultas"></span></h4>
  </div>
  <h3>SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE?</h3>
  <button id="clear-consults">Delete Consultas</button>
  <div class="control-buttons">
    <button id="dntdelete">Cancel</button>
    <button id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button id="create">Create</button>
  </div>
  <div id="confirm"></div>
  <pre id="json"></pre>
</main>
```

**style.css**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: serif;
}

body,
html {
  padding: 20px;
}

main {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, max-content);
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #4c5f6b;
}
.control-buttons {
  display: none;
  gap: 20px;
}
button {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #4c5f6b;

  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#cancel {
  background-color: #4c5f6b;
}
#delete {
  background-color: #89608e;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
#create {
  background-color: #6eaa8d;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.results {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
.results h4 {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.results span {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px 9px;
  border: 2px solid #6eaa8d;
}
#confirm {
  display: none;
}
pre {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: it throws this error **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'** on this line **consultas.textContent = lS[0]?.consultas?.length || 0;**

Comment: This is only for a visual part `consultas.textContent = lS[0]?.consultas?.length || 0`, but i did update without question mark the snippet and link above. And try to clean up your `localStorage`.

Comment: Yeah! I deleted the offending lines, and it works perffectly. Now I'm going to integrate your solution within my code and let you know.

Comment: But when I integrated your code within my enviroment it throw more errors like the  kind of **expecting something and got this** and also breaks the rest of the page code. Just to add that the **f7Contacts** string I put in my question is just the data about one single contact. There are many more and all must need **consultas** to be deleted at once.

Comment: **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'** at this line **deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', removeItem);** (really don't understand)

Comment: I did update the snippet and link above for array. Before it was for one item in the array. I suppose it should work.

Comment: **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'**  after `document.getElementById('confirm').style.display="block";` you have **curly braces**

Comment: Now it's working as needed. It deletes all the **consultas** from all the contacts. Thank you very much for this one too. It's been a real headache to me. I've got still another unanswered question. I will bountify it to see if someone answers. Would it be you too?

Answer (score 1):

when you read a particular item from `localStorage` it returns a string, and there is no way to remove some particular item from the saved data, but you can convert the saved data to a Object

and then use `delete` operator to delete anything from that object

```
// This is Sample Data for demonstration purposes
// And from this sample data i want to remove this Gender item
const data = {
  name: "Andrew",
  email: "example@example.com",
  gender: "male"
}

// Here you set your Data by Converting it into a String using JSON.stringify()
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data))

console.log(localStorage.getItem('data'))
// Prints out {"name":"Andrew","email":"example@example.com","gender":"male"}

let storedData = localStorage.getItem('data') // Get Data from localStorage
let newData = JSON.parse(storedData) // Convert it back into a object using JSON.parse()

delete newData.gender // Then remove a item using delete operator
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(newData)) // Saving to LocalStorafe
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')))
// Prints Out {name: "Andrew", email: "example@example.com"}
```

[image: Check this image for output]

Read More About `Delete` Operator at [MDN Documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Edit to remove the item you wanted try this out:

```js
var contacts = { f7Contacts: [{
    "id": "95470e9e-ee5c-4467-9500-1fcbeae1b57c",
    "hasPic": true,
    "picId": 3,
    "createdOn": "2021-08-01T17:31:32.230Z",
    "firstName": "Fulano Menganejo Ciclanejo",
    "company": "La Fábrica",
    "job": "Barrendero",
    "mobile": "+53555555",
    "phone": "+5372222222",
    "sms": "",
    "email": "fulano@nauta.cu",
    "madedate": "Invalid date",
    "clinic": "2",
    "gender": "M",
    "birthday": "Invalid date",
    "age": "47",
    "visitings": [{
        "id": "1",
        "vdate": "19/07/-2006 12:00 AM",
        "pdcb": "Est officia dolorem ",
        "vdiagnose": "Laborum Ea consecte",
        "vrecom": "Mollit cillum sed pe",
        "nextv": "Invalid date" }],

    "consultas": [{
        "id": "1",
        "ldate": "04/07/-1978 12:00 AM",
        "lmotive": "Soluta cumque aspern",
        "ldiagnose": "Quidem autem do ut o",
        "ttest": "Rerum sint atque il",
        "etest": "Officiis deserunt un",
        "mtest": "Nihil a dolore rem s",
        "nextv": "Invalid date" },

        {"id": "2",
        "ldate": "04/04/-1991 12:00 AM",
        "lmotive": "Eius in est enim no",
        "ldiagnose": "In aliqua Sunt dol",
        "ttest": "Sunt dolor eu sed N",
        "etest": "Quia aut reprehender",
        "mtest": "Unde libero autem an",
        "nextv": "Invalid date"
    }],

    "isFavorite":true
    }]
};

console.log(contacts.f7Contacts[0].hasOwnProperty("consultas"));
// Prints true

delete contacts.f7Contacts[0].consultas

console.log(contacts.f7Contacts[0].hasOwnProperty("consultas"));
// Prints False
```

So i already told you what `delete` operator does, now just by using delete see how you can delete a item!

Explaination: well `Object.hasOwnProperty(property)` simple returns `true` if that given object has a property, in our example it's *consultas* and it returns `false` if that object has no property like that!

Read About `Object.hasOwnProperty(property)` at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: CMORADE DEV, thanks for your answer, your code works perfectly on its own but I can not manage to make it delete the stuff I need. Look at my JSON array and you will realise that what I need to detele is not a simple item from an array but a complete array embeeded into a larger array. There is an array named **f7Contacts** and inside of it there are, let's say it this way, some sub arrays named **visitings** and **consultas** and what I need to delete here is **consultas**.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer but I'm so sorry for not being able to make it work in any way. Should it help if I tell you that **f7Contacts** is stored by a function some where else in the app, so it's already stored in **localStorage** and now I just need to create a function to delete **consultas** via a button. When I try to integrate your approach within my code it simply returns this **TypeError: contacts.f7Contacts is undefined**. I think I will leave it alone for a while for my sake, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

**Updates: Call delete function on Button Click and Delete all consultas from F7Contacts.**

```
 var contacts = [{
    "id": "95470e9e-ee5c-4467-9500-1fcbeae1b57c",
    "hasPic": true,
    "picId": 3,
    "createdOn": "2021-08-01T17:31:32.230Z",
    "firstName": "Fulano Menganejo Ciclanejo",
    "company": "La Fábrica",
    "job": "Barrendero",
    "mobile": "+53555555",
    "phone": "+5372222222",
    "sms": "",
    "email": "fulano@nauta.cu",
    "madedate": "Invalid date",
    "clinic": "2",
    "gender": "M",
    "birthday": "Invalid date",
    "age": "47",
    "visitings": [{
        "id": "1",
        "vdate": "19/07/-2006 12:00 AM",
        "pdcb": "Est officia dolorem ",
        "vdiagnose": "Laborum Ea consecte",
        "vrecom": "Mollit cillum sed pe",
        "nextv": "Invalid date" }],
    
    "consultas": [{
        "id": "1",
        "ldate": "04/07/-1978 12:00 AM",
        "lmotive": "Soluta cumque aspern",
        "ldiagnose": "Quidem autem do ut o",
        "ttest": "Rerum sint atque il",
        "etest": "Officiis deserunt un",
        "mtest": "Nihil a dolore rem s",
        "nextv": "Invalid date" },
    
        {"id": "2",
        "ldate": "04/04/-1991 12:00 AM",
        "lmotive": "Eius in est enim no",
        "ldiagnose": "In aliqua Sunt dol",
        "ttest": "Sunt dolor eu sed N",
        "etest": "Quia aut reprehender",
        "mtest": "Unde libero autem an",
        "nextv": "Invalid date"
    }],
    
    "isFavorite":true
    }]
    
    localStorage.setItem("f7Contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
```

**Delete all consultas from F7Contacts:**

```
function removeItem() {
      var contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Contacts")) || {}; //fetch f7Contacts from storage
        for (var k = 0; k < contacts.length; k++) { 
              delete contacts[k].consultas; 
         }
        localStorage.setItem("f7Contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
     }
```

**Call delete function on Button Click:**

```
 function clearConsults(){         
   console.log((localStorage.f7Contacts));        
   removeItem();      
   console.log((localStorage.f7Contacts)); 
}
```

Comment: Kiran, thanks a lot. This stuff was really driving me crazy. Your function deletes the stuff but it does just by running the code and I need to delete it by a button click.

Comment: You can call `removeItem(0)` from `clearConsults()` function.

Comment: @simbiosis,    `function clearConsults(){
        console.log((localStorage.f7Contacts));
        removeItem(0); 
    console.log((localStorage.f7Contacts));
}`

Comment: I manage to integrate your code into my enviroment and it deletes the **consultas** but just to the first contact in the string, the rest of the contacts keep theirs. What to change on the code so it can manage to delete the **consultas** of all the contacts inside **f7Contacts**?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS, i have updated the code to delete all consultas from f7Contacts.

Comment: Kiran, your answer works too but I did accept ЖнецЪ because it was more complete and integrated better within my project. Thank you very much for your time and effort. There is still another unanswered question I need to solve to move on with this poject. May you take a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Obtain your locastorage data and parse it into an object:

```
let f7ContactsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts'))
```

Step 2: loop your parsed JavaScript object to remove the consulatas array:

```
if(Array.isArray(f7ContactsArray)){
   f7ContactsArray = f7ContactsArray.map(contact => {
     delete contact.consultas; //use object delete to remove the property
     return contact;
   })
}
```

Step 3: replace the localStorage key with updated contact array:

```
localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify(f7ContactsArray))
```

Using a method just do something like:

```
const clearConsults = () => {
  let f7ContactsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts'));
  if(Array.isArray(f7ContactsArray)){
       f7ContactsArray = f7ContactsArray.map(contact => {
         delete contact.consultas; //use object delete to remove the property
         return contact;
       });

       localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify(f7ContactsArray))
  }
  
}

<main>
<div class="results">
<h4>Consultas<span id="consultas"></span></h4>
</div>
<div class="control-buttons">
<div id="confirm" style="display: none">
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
<button id="dntdelete">Cancel</button>
</div>
<a onclick="clearConsults()">Delete Consultas</a><h3>SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE?</h3>
</div>
</main>
```

NOTE: Ensure your JavaScript file or method is included via the script tag in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for doing that operation as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) on MDN.

But you can do it yourself with something like:

```
// Original state
const state = {
    id: 100,
    name: 'Karen',
    test: true   <--- initial creation of key we'll delete
}

// Save state
localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state))

console.log(state)

// Example of removing a single key from an object within localStorage
const modifiedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))

// Delete the `test` key
delete modifiedState.test

// Update storage
localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(modifiedState))

// Show the updated state directly from localStorage
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state')))
```

Comment: I really don't understand. If I'm going to `delete modifiedState.test`, where this `modifiedState.test` was created in first instance? because I can not see it clear.

Comment: I've updated to make it a bit clearer. If you run these lines step-by-step in the console, it will make sense.

Comment: Joshua, your code works well on itself but when applied to my enviroment it just do nothing.  This is what I did `function clearConsults(){ const modifiedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Contacts')) delete modifiedState.consultas localStorage.setItem('f7Contacts', JSON.stringify(modifiedState)) }`